# asp.net core 2.2 using HttpCookieCollection in a class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am "upgrading" from old .net to .net core 2.2 (obviously it's not such as easy upgrade as it is a re-write)

> This `HttpCookieCollection` is not so accessible anymore.  For .Net Core 2.2 class library what are some examples of how to get access to this cookie collection?

```
private static string CollectionToHtmlTable(HttpCookieCollection collection)
{
    // Converts HttpCookieCollection to NameValueCollection
    var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    foreach (string item in collection)
    {
        var httpCookie = collection[item];
        if (httpCookie != null)
        {
            nvc.Add(item, httpCookie.Value);
        }
    }

    return CollectionToHtmlTable(nvc);
}
```

Comment: Basically this `HttpCookieCollection` is NOT found in my code to upgrade to .net core and it is in a class library

Comment: How did you call `CollectionToHtmlTable` in old .net? Share us the code which you need to call `CollectionToHtmlTable`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the equivalent class would be [`IRequestCookieCollection`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http.Features/src/IRequestCookieCollection.cs)

An instance of this object can be accessed in the request instance via `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Cookies using HttpContext

For this you would want to inject IHttpContextAccessor. the usage is:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    public MyClass (IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    { 
         _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public void MyFunction()
    {
         var someCookie = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["someCookie"];
    }
}
```

If you are in the controller, you can directly use `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["someCookie"]`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        var someCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["someCookie"];

        return View();
    }
}
```